# How to join two queries as one in whereIn

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 I have these queries:

```
$manager = DB::table('hr_employees')
    ->select('line_manager_id')
    ->where('hr_status',0)
    ->whereIn('employee_code', $employee_with_goals)
    ->get();

$employee_with_goals = DB::table('hr_employees')
    ->join('appraisal_goals', 'hr_employees.employee_code', '=', 'appraisal_goals.employee_code')
    ->select('hr_employees.employee_code')
    ->where('hr_employees.company_id', $userCompany)
    ->where('hr_employees.hr_status',0)
    ->where('appraisal_goals.is_published', '=', '1')
    ->where('appraisal_goals.is_approved', '=', '3')            
    ->groupBy('hr_employees.employee_code')
    ->get();
```

$manager is the main query

How do I combine these two queries as one using $employee_with_goals  as the variable in whereIn()?

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title. That's redundant noise that provides no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`pluck` method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck) to retrieve all values for a given key in a collection:

```
$manager = DB::table('hr_employees')
    ->select('line_manager_id')
    ->where('hr_status',0)
    ->whereIn('employee_code', $employee_with_goals->pluck('employee_code'))
    ->get();
```

---

You can actually use a subquery too:

```
$manager = DB::table('hr_employees')
    ->select('line_manager_id')
    ->where('hr_status',0)
    ->whereIn('employee_code', function ($query) use ($userCompany) {
        $query
            ->table('hr_employees')
            ->select('hr_employees.employee_code')
            ->join('appraisal_goals', 'hr_employees.employee_code', '=', 'appraisal_goals.employee_code')
            ->where('hr_employees.company_id', $userCompany)
            ->where('hr_employees.hr_status',0)
            ->where('appraisal_goals.is_published', '=', '1')
            ->where('appraisal_goals.is_approved', '=', '3')            
            ->groupBy('hr_employees.employee_code')
    })
    ->get();
```

The code above is untested.